# PostgreSQL improperly sorts unicode chars with Czech collation

Tags: postgresql, locale

I have a table with collation set to cs_CZ (Czech):

```
    Name   | Encoding |  Collation  |    CType
-----------+----------+-------------+-------------
 foo       | UTF8     | cs_CZ.UTF-8 | cs_CZ.UTF-8
```

but when I order by string, result is not sorted as it should be according to Czech alphabet:

```
=> SELECT surname FROM foo ORDER BY surname;
     surname     
-----------------
A
Da
Ďb
Dc
E
```

So it is sorted like if the unicode accent character (Ď) was converted to its ASCII version without accent (D). But the Czech alphabet is: ... C -> D -> Ď -> E ..., so the returned order is incorrect (in this example it should be: A -> Da -> Dc -> Ďb -> E).

Is this usual PostgreSQL behavior? Is there a way how get it sorted correctly according to Czech alphabet?

**EDIT:** Tried on Postgres 9.1.4, both have the same behavior. It is an Arch Linux machine.
**EDIT2:** Adjusted example, the Ď is the real problem.

Comment: Please tell us which version of PostgreSQL you are using.

Comment: Just in chance, do you happen to be on PostgreSQL 9.1 or a more recent version? If so, is the *surname* column in your *foo* table set to a different collation?

Comment: Sorry, it is Postgres 9.1.4 and it is the same on 9.2.4. Question updated. And no, there is no column-specific collation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct. Accent for á, ď, é, ě, í, ň, ó, ť, ú, ů, ý should be ignored see [article](http://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/?id=900)

Czech sort rules are little bit complex :)

Comment: I'm using Postgres FTS for searching with the English language at this moment so now I need Czech as well, I have checked everywhere for adding pg_ts_config for Czech, but no luck. I have tried to add pg_ts_config for Czech manually but have not succeeded. May I know the right way? @pavel-stehule

Comment: @PankajSavaliya - Czech language is not supported by default. You can find Czech dictionary for PostgreSQL fulltext on internet - https://github.com/char0n/postgresql-czech-fulltext/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, as it's the manual way. I hope Postgres will add more by default.

Comment: @PankajSavaliya - I afraid so it never be. The snowball doesn't work extra well for Czech language, and dictionary is just too long for distribution to all users. More only 10M peoples uses this language.

Comment: I have added it to our database in Postgres and tested it also with the # \dF and select to_tsvector('czech'::regconfig, 'test');  commands and it shows me Czech in that list and succeeded. but now the point turn to rank related, it's show me wrong SearchRank with config(czech).   as the concern might releated to "á, ď, é, ě, í, ň, ó, ť, ú, ů, ý" . what should I do for that?

Comment: @PankajSavaliya - maybe it is related badly configured encoding.

Comment: I have generated to_tsvector perfectly while updating/creating for indexing, and it's working for English well,  so for Czech just changed config with the language name.

Is there any required for URL encoding or something else that I missed for Czech? @Pavel Stehule

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL does not have its own sort rules, it uses the rules provided by the operating system. If you try with `/usr/bin/sort` with the same locale, you'll get the same sort order.

Here's the result with your sample data when tried with Ubuntu 12.04, PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
create COLLATION cs_CZ (locale="cs_CZ.UTF-8");
select * from (values('Ca'),('Čb'),('Cc')) as l(a) order by a collate cs_CZ;
```

Result:

```
 a  
----
 Ca
 Cc
 Čb
(3 rows)
```

Notice that it's sorted as you say it should.

If your operating system sorts differently and you're sure that it's wrong according to official czech rules, then it's a bug in its czech locale implementation.

UPDATE following comment:

```
 SELECT * FROM (values('A'),('Da'),('Ďb'),('Dc'),('E')) AS l(a)
   ORDER BY a COLLATE cs_CZ;
```

results in:

```
 a  
----
 A
 Da
 Ďb
 Dc
 E
```

Comment: I'm sorry, byt the example I used actually works - I mistakenly assumed it affects all letters. The problem is with letter D (Ď). Could you please try the same with this set: ```SELECT * FROM (values('A'),('Da'),('Ďb'),('Dc'),('E')) AS l(a) ORDER BY a COLLATE cs_CZ;```? What is the result then?

Answer (score 1):

sorting in czech collation is correct by [czech grammar rules!](http://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/?id=900)

Characters like á, ď, é, ě, í, ň, ó, ť, ú, ů, ý are sorted like they don't have punctuation so result:

A, Da, Ďb, Dc, E is corret by czech grammar.

For Slovak and Czech it can sounds crazy, but "rules as rules".

Other rules are for slovak language [(collate sk_SK)](http://jazykovaporadna.sme.sk/q/2736/) where characters d-ď, t-ť, n-ň, l-ľ are in alphabetical order like czech Ď in this case.